# When I use range.offset in VBA, I get error code 1004 application defined object or object defined error due to synatx error

Tags: vba, variables, range, offset

I am trying to use the offset function and cannot figure out the problem with my synatx.

I copied this code from another question about offset on this website.

I want to look for a string in column X (starting at X9 always) and if present, I want to know the value of the cell that is two columns over and in the same row.

I would like to use the offset value in an additional part of the same code, so it needs to be named as a variable, but I decided to see if I could first get VBA to at least read the information I want, hence the message box.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim LeftStrike As Range
Dim FrameLeftStrike As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set LeftStrike = Range("X9:X" & lastRow)
Set FrameLeftStrike = Range("LeftStrike").Offset(0, 4).Value
For Each FrameLeftStrike In LeftStrike
    If InStr(1, LeftStrike.Value, "Foot Strike") > 0 Then
        MsgBox FrameLeftStrike
    End If
Next FrameLeftStrike
End Sub
```

The variable "FrameLeftStrike" is the problem.

I receive:

> application defined or object defined error.

I tried different iterations.

If I change the line of code to,

```
Set FrameLeftStrike = Sheet4.Range("LeftStrike").Offset(0, 4).Value
```

I get the same error.

If I change it to

```
Set FrameLeftStrike = LeftStrike.Offset(0, 4).Value
```

I get

> run-time error '424' Object required.

I want to use this code in the active sheet only, but the name of the active sheet will change as it will get copied as a template for other projects.

Comment: Remove the `.Value` - you have your variable defined as a Range so you need to give it a range, not a value. Also, if you want the value 2 cells over, you need to swap your 4 with a 2. (negative to go left 2 cells and positive to go right 2 cells).  Your loop looks circular as well - I believe your offset needs to be inside the loop. Can you share the details of what you are trying to do with your loop

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I just want the loop to read through column X and tell me each time the string "foot strike" appears. If it does appear in column x, then I want to know the frame number, which is in the same row 2 columns over (I fixed the 4 to a 2, thanks for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Loop through each cell (`my_cell`) in Column X (`my_range`)
2. Individually check if the cell contains `Foot Strike`
3. If so, return the value 2 cells to right in a `MsgBox`

---

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update

Dim my_range As Range, my_cell As Range
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("X" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set my_range = ws.Range("X9:X" & lr)

For Each my_cell In my_range
    If InStr(my_cell, "Foot Strike") Then
        MsgBox my_cell.Offset(0, 2)
    End If
Next my_cell


End Sub
```